# How to set Marker location to users current location onInit, using react-native-maps and Marker Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

Now react native maps only gets marker location on tap of the MapView

```
        <MapView scrollEnabled={true} style={styles.map} region={region} onPress={selectLocationHandler}>
            {markerCoordinates && <Marker title="picked Location" draggable={true}
        isPreselected={true} coordinate={markerCoordinates}></Marker>}
        </MapView>
```

I want to have my current location marked without tapping on the mapview

I have the following code for MapView and Marker

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
       position => {
            const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
            this.marker._component.animateMarkerToCoordinate(
                { latitude,longitude },
                500);
   });
}
```

with `this._marker`as your marker ref